# Linux - Syntax error when issuing command

Tags: linux, bash

I get a syntax error when using the following if condition in a bash script.

```
if [ -f $pid_file ] && [ $check_run_proc == *"my_proc"* ] && kill -0 $(cat "$pid_file"); then
```

Can you please identify what the problem is?

Thank you.

Comment: the star symbol... you mean `*`?

Comment: thanks for replying, yes indeed, because I am trying to match the string my_proc inside the variable $check_run_proc which gets the PID of the process while running..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use bash's `[[` special word and the `=~` operator to match regular expressions. That `if`-clause should do it:

```
if [ -f "$pid_file" ] && [[ "$check_run_proc" =~ "my_proc" ]] && 
   kill -0 $(cat "$pid_file"); then
```

Comment: It's fixed now, thank you so much!

I am having a bit issue with kill -0 $(cat "$pid_file") though

basically if the pid file does not exist, I get error on the terminal, of course the script works

is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: it seems I didn't have this one before, maybe some of the symbols added have something to do with it?